# pulling question bank out of Moodle

Tags: moodle

I have 3 different Moodle databases, each one represents a school, I want to built an external question bank that can be accessed by these 3 schools as follows :

when a teacher creates a new quiz, the quiz editing page will look like the same of Moodle's one, the same question bank, but this page actually reads its content from an external question bank system, the teacher adds, deletes and updates questions in the bank as usual, the only difference here is that the questions come from that external question bank database and not from Moodle's database.

what are the important points to consider before starting to build such question bank ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the Moodle XML export/import schema and rather than building a completely independent question just developing a broker service that can export new/updated questions into an XML store and then export/import them into the other sites. Developing 2 web services to handle import / export could be a much quicker route and requires no new interfaces for teachers.

In the broker system you'll need to handle teachers changing the same question on multiple sites and possible duplication but that should be a relatively simple mapping or could be ignored if you just create new questions and leave updates. You could then build a broker interface to configure this more effectively as required.

The other alternative is to look at the [opaque question behaviour](https://moodle.org/plugins/view.php?plugin=qbehaviour_opaque) which should enable you to deliver remote questions from within Moodle. You could then make use of something like [OpenMark](http://www.open.ac.uk/openmarkexamples/overview) if it was suitable to your question types.